# Error while inserting duplicate values into DP , using ON Duplicate Key using python mysql DB

Tags: python, mysql, sql-insert, mysql-python

These are the following entries in Table MyTable

```
mysql> select * from myTable;
+------+--------+------+
| id   | name   | age  |
+------+--------+------+
|  110 | c      | 23   |
|  114 | chadns | 897  |
| 1112 | chadns | 897  |
+------+--------+------+
```

This is the schema of MyTable

```
mysql> desc myTable;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(3)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| age   | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

While Executing the following code i am getting the following error

```
    import MySQLdb

con_local =  MySQLdb.connect( host ="127.0.0.1",user = "root",passwd ="ctl",db ="ads")
cursor_local = con_local.cursor()

cursor_local.execute("select * from myTable")
x = cursor_local.fetchall()



for i in x:

    s = "insert into myTable values(%d,%s,%s) on duplicate key update id = id+1000"

    cursor_local.execute('''insert into myTable values(%d,%s,%s) on duplicate key update id = id+1000'''%(i[0],i[1],i[2]));
    cursor_local.execute("commit");
```

ERRORS:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chandu.py", line 15, in <module>
    cursor_local.execute('''insert into Chandana values(%d,%s,%s) on duplicate key update id = id+1000'''%(i[0],i[1],i[2]));
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'c' in 'field list'")
```

I am trying to insert duplicate values but changing the primary key id , but it is not working can anyone tell me the solution

Comment: `execute('''` why 3 single quotes open?

Comment: You either need to quote the strings in the query, or use a prepared query like in Alex's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
cursor_local.execute("insert into myTable values(%d,%s,%s) on duplicate key update id = id+1000",(int(i[0]),i[1],i[2]));
```

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 159, in execute
    query = query % db.literal(args)
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str

Comment: i am using %d which cant concatenate with a string so

Comment: `i[0]` is a string, but integer should be there